# Python 2.7 wiki

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, specific-language

Related to [this meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5451/52915).

The [Python 2.7 wiki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/python-2.7/info) states (emphasis mine):

> Use this tag if you are specifically using Python 2.7. **Such questions should be tagged with [python] as well.**

Why? The tagging with Python is confusing enough already. Either put a specific tag on it, or a generic. There's no need for both.

Comment: Because the more generic categorization is useful as well? We encourage the same thing for [vba], [excel-vba], [access-vba], etc on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I know all versions of Python, the easiest way for me to look at all of the Python questions isn't for me to come up with some complicated search that makes sure I'm including all the possible Python tags.  The easiest way is for all of the Python questions to have the [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) tag.  The version specific tag ([python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7)) just provides the additional detail that the question (and answers) should be compatible with the 2.7 version of Python.

A question would be better off tagging [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), omitting [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7), and then specifying that requirement in the body of the question than it would to have the [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) tag and omit the [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) tag.

Comment: The real problem is that python often gets confused with python3, the specific tag fixes that problem.

Comment: Then add the specific tag to the question.  But don't omit **[python]**.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can search for `[*python*]` to get all the questions with a Python-related tag.

Comment: @alexwlchan That's different from specifying **[python]** as a favorited tag that you're following.