# python-3.x tag does not pass lang-py to code-prettify

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, syntax-highlighting

I asked a [Python 3 question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159186/counting-increasing-subsequences-with-a-hackers-binary-index-tree/159214), and tagged it [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x). The highlighting was [messed up](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/12179121/24441389/a1d41f70-1416-11e7-8cc6-5f9db53b0862.png), because the [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag wasn't passing the `lang-py` argument to the JS script that handles the syntax highlighting. I submitted this as an [issue](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/482#issuecomment-289981475) on GitHub, but it couldn't be reproduced because a mod had came along and added the [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, which fixes the syntax highlighting.

TL;DR: If you ask a [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) question but only tag it [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), the syntax highlighting gets messed up.

Answer (score 3):

On Code Review, when you ask a Python question that only works in one of the versions, Python 3, then you should tag it with both the language tag [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) and the version tag [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x). One explanation as to why we do this can be found [in this answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5458).

---

And so, sure it's a bug, but if we stick to the way that we are already tagging Python questions then it doesn't affect us.

Comment: Not a bug. The tag info simply doesn't specify a language for syntax highlighting. I'll discuss this with the other mods, but it feels like "status-bydesign", to ensure all Python questions are tagged with [tag:python].