# Can't get the syntax highlighting for Go

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The syntax highlighting (for Go) does not seem to be applied for this question: [db access wrapper for Go project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/167372/80949)

I tried to apply it manually to my answer (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/169234/80949), using `<!-- language-all: lang-go -->`, but it looks worst than in the question!

I know that syntax highlighting for Go can look better on CR (see [Generate thousands of JSON documents in Go](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/168955/80949)): how can we fix this?

---

**Edit** this is probably related to the `database` tag (as [Peilonrayz](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7354/cant-get-the-syntax-highlighting-for-go?noredirect=1#comment16977_7354) noticed): if you remove it, the syntax highlighting works fine.

A bug remains: why can't I force the `go` highlighting on a `database` question?

Comment: I removed the [tag:database] tag from the question in the edit screen, and it changed the code to what you expected. Aside: I personally don't know why that tag changes syntax highlighting...

Comment: From what I understand, the tag is an hint for the right syntax highlighting. In this case it seems to be an obstacle to language customization.

Answer (score 5):

The tag didn't have an associated syntax highlighter, so the highlighting you'd get with the [go](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) tag alone would have been the default one.

```
<!-- language: lang-go -->
```

should actually be

```
<!-- language: lang-golang -->
```

That's the highlighter I've just associated with the [go](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) tag, so all GO questions and answers should now have correct & proper syntax highlighting... Unless some erroneous `<!-- language` hint is in place.

> *Aside: I personally don't know why that tag changes syntax highlighting... – Peilonrayz*

You don't get to see it, but tags' Info page have a syntax highlighting dropdown that determines how a given tag affects how code gets syntax-highlighted in a post. In the case of GO, that dropdown was set to "none".

Comment: Oh look, there's a syntax highlighting dropdown! Seems like I haven't visited a tag info page since I became a moderator. Shame on me.

Comment: When I said the 'aside', my main point was, 'I don't know why the [tag:database] tag would have the syntax highlighting specified to anything but "none"'. That must have been unclear of me, sorry.

Comment: @Peilonrayz ha! correct - it was set to `lang-sql`, I've just set it to `none`. Thanks! ..side-effect of this being any [tag:database] post without a [tag:sql] tag just lost its syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Kinda reminds me of [how the Python tags work](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7260). There shouldn't be any like that IMO anyway, :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug You mean [questions like a few of these?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database%20-sql%20-java%20-ruby%20-php%20-go%20-c%23%20-python%20-swift%20-javascript%20-c%2b%2b%20-c%20-kotlin%20-vb.net%20-haskell%20-prolog%20-vba%20-perl%20-vbscript%20-php5) ?

Comment: @SimonForsberg from a quick look at a couple of them, yes, indeed - and it's much better that way! (none of the 5-6 ones I opened had actual SQL in them)