# Warn if question is tagged with [python-3.x] but not [python]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, site-policy, editor

Given that 16/50 of the latest [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) questions aren't posted with the [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) tag,<sup>[[1]](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpython-3.x%5D&room=8595)</sup> and site policy is to tag with both.<sup>[[2]](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5458)</sup> Can we move the burden onto the poster to tag properly, rather than have other users clean this up?

I think this number has increased lately; this may be because of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325627).

I think this is important, as RSS feeds only go off the tags the post is posted with, not what it is edited to include.

Comment: Does a related feature already exist anywhere else on the SE network? If not, I doubt this is going to happen.

Comment: @Mast Given SE's track record of ignoring bugs and feature requests, even if the fix to the bug is provided in the answers. I doubt this would be implemented any time soon, if ever. There are already custom warn boxes in the editor.

Comment: Warn boxes, yea, we got a couple of those. I never felt like they helped much, since people don't read. Especially new people, which are probably the main offenders here.

Comment: But sure, adding them would be nice. Might save us at least a bit of work.

Comment: There's also [python-2], and the [c++] and its numerous versions, and probably others.  Should those also be handled by this feature?  It would need to be general.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes, it would be nice if it were general. As I mostly monitor the [tag:python] tag, I can't comment [c++] or any other similar tags. I didn't mention [tag:python-2.x] mostly as it's a lot more quite and isn't as large Python 3.x to deal with. Where it's stats are ~30% wrong tags at 80 questions per month. (~30 questions per month, these stats should be taken with a chunk of salt)

Comment: How about making language tags mandatory like [tag:discussion] or [tag:feature-request], etc on meta? This way you would be forced to always pick one?

Comment: @t3chb0t It'd be cool if that were a thing, but I don't think SE will approve. :(

Answer (score 3):

After discussing this internally, we've decided to pass on adding explicit support for dependent tags at this time.

Creating nested categories is certainly a legitimate way to organize content, but the system was designed around *ad hoc* tagging methods, so we've always resisted building and enforcing tagging hierarchies.

Certainly, you are free to create guidelines about how your content should be tagged, but we are not going to be directly supporting dependent tagging at this time.

Comment: Thank you for not taking years to respond. Otherwise this is an, expected, shame.